# Kubectl get nodes -o wide doesn't have an external IP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am currently learning Kubernetes. But I don't have an External IP when I run kubectl get nodes -o wide. I tried using minikube ip, but no luck. Minikube ip also returns the internal IP. Please help me with this.

[Screenshot of kubectl get nodes -o wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs20L.png)

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/kubernetes-and-docker-desktop-how-to-set-up-external-ip-for-the-node/87823/3

Comment: What IP did you expect instead?

Answer (score 0):

External IP is populated if the cluster is provisioned in the cloud like AWS or Azure.